# Android Menu Banner not appearing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm new to android and I'm having issues getting my menu to display on screen. I'm not to sure where the issue might be, so I've put a few files below that might hold the issue. For your information, the app does run, and it displays a list of dummy data detailed in one of the methods of ForecastFragment, it just doesn't show the menu.

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.forecast_fragment, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

### ForecastFragment.java

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {
private ArrayAdapter<String> data;

public ForecastFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //statement below allows for fragment to handle menu interface
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecast_fragment, menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
        weatherTask.execute("85383");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
} [two more methods below which do not pertain to the menu]
```

### menu_main.xml

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

### forecast_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

I'm not sure whether I need the menu_main.xml if I also have the forecast_fragment.xml, so I would like to know if one of them is extraneous and if I can delete one of those file. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Try adding this line `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`  in `MainActivity` the same as you have done in `ForecastFragment`

Comment: Alright, I could do that, but I would need MainActivity.java to extend Fragment instead of FragmentActivity, which would then make some of the other methods in MainActivty undefined. Would this really be the solution, then?

Comment: My suggestion for you is -  to extend `ActionBarActivity` instead, and all the other methods will work fine because `ActionBarActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: I have extended the ActionBarActivity to MainActivity, but it does not seem to get me the `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`. Is there something else I can extend that maybe has that method?

Comment: Oh, never mind, I see what you meant. Extend ActionBarActivity, take out setHasOptionsMenu. Thank's for the help